# take screenshot of an app that is running in backgroud - android

Tags: android, screenshot

My goal is to take a screenshot of an App that is running in parallel. For example I have opened WhatsApp in background. If I press on a button an my App it should automatically take a screenshot of the WhatsApp surface without opening WhatsApp and with the lowest latency possible.
After taking the screenshot it should appear on my app. Is that possible in any way? Is root required?

Comment: its named _screenshot_ for a reason

Comment: This is not possible to do, it would be a security problem to allow another app to see the content of another app with ease. Security is there for a reason. If this was to be doable. Root may be required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't make a screenshot of an app that is running in backgroud.

**Only the thing that is on the foreground**.

A screenshot, screen capture, screen cap, cap, screen dump, or screengrab is an image taken by a person to record the visible items displayed on the monitor, television, or other visual output device in use.

On most Android phones, you can take a screenshot by holding down the Sleep/wake button and the volume-down button simultaneously. Hold these buttons down until your screen flashes.

Comment: @BuddyHop if you have android studio, and project, i recommend you to use android device monitor. (if you have to do many of them)
You have phone screen on your computer, and one click to make screenshot.